# Facebook Sign In - request only email, not the profile picture, name etc

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

In my app, I only need to request the e-mail address, I don't need other information. However, when I set the permissions to email only:

```
let fbButton = FBLoginButton()
fbButton.permissions = ["email"]
```

It will also request name and profile picture:

[image]

Is it possible to request only the email address ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to request only the email address ?

No, that is not possible.

Users automatically share name and profile picture with any app they log into.

This is part of the [`public_profile`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/public_profile) permission, that is granted to every app when the user logs in, without the app having to specifically ask for it.